# how to indent text in a div outside the div

Tags: html, css

here is the code... http://jsfiddle.net/jpBU6/3/

how do I make the text display higher, and still making the containing div height automated to text length??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style='position:relative; ' >
 <div id="topBody"></div>
 <div id="real-body-top"></div>
 <div id="boddy-middle" style='margin:4px 0px 0px 20px; overflow:auto; ' >
  asdasd asdas dasdas as dasd as dasdas asdasd asdas dasdas as dasd as dasdas asdasd asdas
  dasdas.
  asdas dasdas as dasd as dasdas asdasd asdas dasdas as dasd as dasdas asdasd asdas dasd
  as as dasd as dasdas asdasd asdas dasdas as dasd as dasdas asdasd asdas dasdas as dasd
  as dasdas asdasd.
 </div>
 <div id="body-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this empty div `<div id="real-body-top"></div>`